# will it auto compile when a razor page file is updated on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Two parts to this question:

1 - when a razor page file (example.cshtml) is updated, will the ASP.NET Core auto compile that file?

2-  when a razor page code-behind file (example.cshtml.cs) is updated, will the ASP.NET Core auto compile that file?

I have many web forms that require maintenance and do not want to have to recompile and publish the whole site files every time a single page is updated if we port to Razor Pages.

Comment: What happened when you tried / tested it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your development environment. Assuming you are using Visual Studio as your IDE, usually yes, you will be both able to update your views and code-behind files during a debugging session, if you are running a debug session, and using a debug build (personally, I have never tried to do this in a non-debug build, as I actually see no point in doing so).

I say "usually" because there are some situations which the IDE is not able to update the code which runs behind your app's deployment. Most of the times, if you just alter the code of method bodies in your code-behind files or change some things at your view, things will work smoothly (although you might notice some delay at the first time you reload a page that has been affected by your changes: this is because the IDE is updating your deployment behind the scenes when you reload that page).

However, if you try to do some more complicated things, like editting the signature of methods, declaring new properties in one of your classes, or injecting new stuff in your views, the development environment might have some trouble to update your deploy. Check the screenshot below for a message given by Visual Studio Community 2017 when I try to add a new parameter to a method of a controller I have in one of my projects: the IDE warns me that it won't be able to upload my deployment in the server, and thus my changes won't be correctly reflected during my current debug.

[image: VS 2017 warning]

Also, one thing to keep in mind is that Visual Studio mostly will only allow you to make editions to your code when you **pause the debug session**. Code will be in read-only state if the application is currently running.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not clear on what does the compiling - the ASP.NET Core or the IDE?  (We're using Visual Studio).  We have two servers - production and test.  We update the files on test and then update on production without using the IDE.